# When installing Runescape: "Error applying transforms. Verify that the specified transform paths are valid"

Tags: technical-issues, oldschool-runescape

I was trying to install a game that used to play when I was young, Runescape.
I didn't enjoy the new version of that, so I tried to download the oldschool Runescape. Happens that after the download, every time I try to install the game I get this error:

[image]

Does anybody know what should I do to get over this error?

Update: I followed your comments and updated my Java, still got the error when I try to install the game, but now I'm already able to play it online in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Do you have Java installed? It sounds to me like Java isn't installed or isn't installed properly, the platform path would be the Windows Java path.

Comment: For what it's worth, this error is somewhat explained on the java site: https://java.com/en/download/help/error_applying_transforms.xml

Comment: Is your system in Portuguese, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change all your language settings to English (dates, system, etc...). This worked for me and I could install it.

After some investigations, I tried to install the client via command-line using -verbose to log what is wrong. Apparently, it does some stuff that requires a transformation ID which is language-dependent.

You can also use RsBuddy.

Comment: It works with the RsBuddy :)